# How to use mod_rewrite to map to a different domain and preserve the original

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, subdomain

For example:

www.example.com and subdomain.mydomain.com are on the same server.

When I put example.com in the address bar, I want it to serve the pages from subdomain.mydomain.com, but still show as example.com in the browser.  So, if the old URL was:

subdomain.mydomain.com/this/stuff?is_cool=yes

the new url would be

www.example.com/this/stuff?is_cool=yes

Comment: Not really programming related. Should be moved to serverfault as it is more of an configuration question.

Comment: True, and the answer is proxypass or dns alias.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple options.

- Write a proxy on example.com that fetches the content from subdomain.mydomain.com and displays it to the user.
- As both sites are on the same server, point example.com's document root to the same spot as subdomain.mydomain.com.
- Use a frameset on example.com with a 100% height frame of subdomain.mydomain.com.